# How to create a paypal billing agreement using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am struggling to understand how the Paypal REST API is used to create and execute a subscription plan using Node.js

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
paypal.configure({
    mode: 'sandbox',
        client_id: secrets.paypal.client_id,
        client_secret: secrets.paypal.client_secret
      });
```

Then I create a billing plan object including a trial period and the normal subscription amount which I pass to the create method, then when I get a response I update it to the 'ACTIVE' state, and then call the get method again which in my understanding should give me links which the user can then use to subscribe to this billing plan.

Am I way off?

```
paypal.billingPlan.create(billingPlanAttributes, function (error, billingPlan) {

  req.session.paymentId = billingPlan.id;
  var BillingID = billingPlan.id;
  var links = billingPlan.links;


  var billing_plan_update_attributes = [
          {
              "op": "replace",
              "path": "/",
              "value": {
                  "state": "ACTIVE"
              }
          }
      ];


  paypal.billingPlan.get(BillingID, function (error, billingPlan) {

          paypal.billingPlan.update(BillingID, billing_plan_update_attributes, function (error, response) {
                  paypal.billingPlan.get(BillingID, function (error, billingPlan) {

                          for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                            if (links[i].rel === 'self') {
                              res.render('api/paypal', {
                                approvalUrl: links[i].href
                              });
                            }
                          }
                  });
          }); // End update

  }); // End get





  });
```